# Firebase get Index of child value programmatically in Android

Tags: android, firebase

Is there any way to get the index of a child of a `Firebase` in Android? Unfortunately I do not have 10 reputation so I'll post my picture here: http://gyazo.com/70d095cfac4fa92ea344e137fa44ef6d

What I want is in someway get the amount of values in a certain child to loop with an index:

```
//For loop/Iterator to get value to store in an array
FireBase.child("Europe").child("Albania").child("answers).child(i).getValue();
```

Comment: Firebase ordered collections are not indexed by your usual sequential index. See this blog post for an explanation: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html You can get the name/id of a node with its key() method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, in the link with the Title: "Arrays in Java". Is it possible to use an iterator from the messages List<String> hasNext() function to add the amount of objects to know how many there are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer that I wanted myself.

```
private int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<your_firebase>/");
        myFirebaseRef.child("Europe").child("Albania").child("answers").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                int length = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                String[] sampleString = new String[length];
                while(i < length) {
                    sampleString[i] = iterator.next().getValue().toString();
                    Log.d(Integer.toString(i), sampleString[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The "i" is the index from which you start from, which is 0 in this case.

```
DataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
```

returns an

```
Iterator<DataSnapshot>
```

i then created the endIndex which is length and looped it through a while-loop. I then created a String array and added all values of the child with

```
iterator.next().getValue().toString();
```

because my object were strings.